# Как сделать и печать ворнинга в stderr и бросание исключения?

Tags: python, python-2.x, pytest

Мне нужно чтобы тесты фейлились при наличии ворнинга. 
Для этого в pytest есть флаг `-W error`, при наличии которого ворнинги бросают исключение, но перестают писать в `stderr`.
Как сделать и то и другое одновременно?

```
def foo():
    warnings.warn('Some warning')


def test_1():
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception:
        processErrors()
```

П.с. Решение ловить ворнинги руками и печатать их самому, к сожалению, не подходит

Comment: pytest же пишет в stderr причину, по которой тест упал. В данной случае это будет варнинг. Или что-то другое нужно?

Comment: С `-W error` не пишет. Вместо этого ворнинг выбрасывает исключение. 
Если в тесткейсах есть что-то вроде
```
try:
    foo()
    warn()
except Exception:
    processException()
```
То ворнинг обработается как будто произошло обычное исключение и поток выполнение пойдет дальше, и сторонний наблюдатель будет в неведении о том что ворнинг был, так как в стдерр ничего не пишется.

Покрыть except Warning все траи мне не подходит. Полагаю что в апи варнингов/пайтеста все же есть что-то подходящее

Comment: вот отсюда https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html - второй пример. Есть ворнинг, тест падает, наблюдатель видит, что тест упал именно по причине наличия ворнинга `UserWarning: api v1, should use functions from v2`

Comment: Тест упал, потому что ворнинг кинул исключение.
Если этот кусок кода завернуть в try: ... except Expection: ... он не упадет и не выведет

Comment: А зачем вам заворачивать их в try? В вопросе наоборот написали, что не хотите их ловить руками

Comment: Еще раз: у меня в тестах УЖЕ есть подобный код. 
Что-то делаем, обрабатываем исключение, что-то делаем дальше. Это нормальный сценарий.  
`
try:
    foo()
except Exception:
    processErrors()
`
Но дело в том, что foo() может кинуть ворнинг, и если это произойдет, никто об этом не узнает - тест не упадет, в стдэрр никчего не напишется.

Comment: Так и надо было написать в вопросе. Ваша проблема не в pytest, а в неправильном отлове исключений. Вместо `except Exception:` явно перечислите возможные классы ошибок (кроме `UserWarning`) и тесты будут падать с флагом `-W error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть флага `-W error` в том, что, если pytest встречает ворнинг, он бросает исключение `UserWarning`, т.е. весь код, что идет в тесте после ворнинга исполнен не будет, тест упадет.

Конструкции `except Exception:` не рекомендуются PEP8. Вот яркий пример как раз у вас. Логика вашего теста будет нарушена, так как pytets кинет исключение `UserWarning`, его отловит ваш `except` и исполнение пойдет в `processErrors()`. И, возможно, будут выполнены какие-то ненужные действия. А если запустить без флага `-W error`, то тест пойдет по другому пути, без `processErrors()`.

Т.е. логика теста будет зависеть от того, с какими вспомогательными параметрами его запускать. Как по мне - это идеологически неправильно.

Рекомендую переписать конструкции `try:... except:...` с явным указанием того, какие исключения вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 1):

`except Exception:` говорит, что `processErrors()` ожидает *в том числе* и UserWarning исключение: значит, либо это проблемы `processErrors()`, чтобы UserWarning обработать (напечатать лог и выбросить его повторно) либо если `processErrors()` *не принимает* UserWarning у вас, тогда `except Exception:` это **баг** в `test_1()`, который следует исправить (чтобы `processError()` вызывалась только для исключений, которые она ожидает, к 
 примеру, заменить на `except ValueError`).